# Another ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I am working on running a Rails application in production. It's still a proof of concept, but I'm running into `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` exceptions for form submissions. My understanding is that in Rails 6 (or maybe earlier?) the `protect_from_forgery` callback is now called by default. To get it to work, I added the configuration option `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false` in my `config/environments/production.rb` file, and now I'm working on re-enabling forgery protection so I removed the override and attempted to submit some forms (or log out, basically anything that uses a POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE method).

My ApplicationController does not call `protect_from_forgery` manually, and all GET requests appear to be working just fine. My `application.html.haml` includes the following within `%head`:

```
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
```

My forms are using `bootstrap_form_with` and the form is submitting an `authenticity_token` form parameter that matches what is in the `%head` (verified from Chrome dev tools and the logs). When I submit, I see that the response is a 422 error with the exception in the logs:

```
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358]   
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:217:in `handle_unverified_request'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:249:in `handle_unverified_request'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] devise (4.7.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:244:in `verify_authenticity_token'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:110:in `block in run_callbacks'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] ahoy_matey (3.0.1) lib/ahoy/controller.rb:45:in `set_ahoy_request_store'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:139:in `run_callbacks'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:259:in `context'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:253:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] turbolinks_render (0.9.17) lib/turbolinks_render/middleware.rb:77:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] ahoy_matey (3.0.1) lib/ahoy/engine.rb:22:in `call_with_quiet_ahoy'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] request_store (1.5.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:77:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
[3d603471-3240-4401-a3a2-e9ba3c6ac358] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I saw that `devise` recommended that I use prepend on the forgery protection, so I added the following to the ApplicationController:

```rb
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
```

I'm a bit stumped as to why this is happening, and can certainly provide some more code samples, but I'm not entirely sure what is necessary.

Thanks so much

Comment: "and all GET requests appear to be working just fine" - CSRF protection has never applied to GET requests. You shouldn't be having issues with the CSRF protection unless you're using forms that are not created with rails helpers and don't include the hidden input tokens. The csrf meta tags are only used for ajax requests. One area that can give problems is caching - for example if you put the meta tags in a fragment cache.

Comment: And I think its been applied by default since at least Rails 4.

Comment: It is using `bootstrap_form_with` (which uses `form_with` internally) and it sends the seemingly correct (the one found in the head section) token as `authenticity_token` in the form data. Unless Rails is caching the items you outlined by default, I am doing no caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, solving this involved enabling the option in `config/environments/production.rb` as shown:

```rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

I'm not sure if this is the only thing, unfortunately, since it was a while since I asked the question, however, after I enabled it request forgery protection started working.